# Display Comments related to a particular product

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

There are three products in my .net web application. By using facebook comment box it is showing same comments for all products. But i want to show the comments related to the particular product. How can i do so?

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Facebook comments are tied to a particular URL. If you can associate a unique URL with each product, you should then be able to request the comments for that URL only, giving you the desired outcome.

Comment: user can add as many number of products as he wants. Then how can i specify URL with that product?

Comment: Without knowing how your site works, I would assume you have some way to Id the products. So you're urls could be of the form example.com/products?productid=id#.

Answer (score 0):

Are your products on different URLs?

If so, and you're using Facebook JS API, your code should look similar to this:

**This is the script embed code**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR-APP-ID-HERE";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

**This is for your comments box**

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="YOUR-URL-HERE" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500"></div>
```

You should substitute in your own Facebook App ID into the embed code and for the comments box, substitute in the product URL into the data-href attribute.

More info here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/